# sql select from then select from where

Tags: sql

I have a table of items that have a user_email as a key to who it belongs to. Normally I

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_email = $1
```

I'd like to add a table that contains the friends of the user. Then id like to be able to change what my query gets by first doing something like

```
SELECT friends_email FROM friends WHERE user_email = $1
```

So then I will get back a group of friends_email(s) and I want to continue my query like

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_email = (any of the friends_emails from the friends query)
```

but I don't know how to set that up. Ive searched for 'nested queries' and have not been able to find anything similar. I may be trying to do the impossible but it seems that i should be able to logically do it. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code for this to include in your question please?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a standard join like this

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN items i
ON  f.friends_email = i.user_mail
WHERE f.user_email = $1
```

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: sweet thank you. I ended up using            SELECT * 
FROM items
LEFT JOIN friends
ON  friends.friend_email = items.user_email
WHERE friends.user_email = $1

Comment: same as yours but more clear for my junior developer mind

Comment: Yes, it more readable, but you will soon get into multiple joins and subselections, it helps to get used to the aliases.